# How to show all the category and all the sub-category in magento?

Tags: magento

In my store, I want to display all the category and sub category in the sidebar.

I got the category but It doesn't show the sub-category products.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?></p>
<ul>
<?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?></p>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><br />
<?php echo $_category->getName() ?><br />
</a>
<?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?><br />
<?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?><br />
<?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>"><br />
<?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?><br />
</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
/ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can any give a suggestion to solve this problem....

Thanks

Comment: "I got the category but It doesn't show the sub-category products." What exactly do you want to display? Only the child categories or the products of the child categories?

Comment: I want both the category and sub category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Sure that your child categories have set 'Yes' for "is anchor" setting. As magento has this filter by default. 
Second thing assign some products to categories and child categories then check it again.

Comment: Thanks sarvagya, But my above code shows ly the default category. Can you help me

Comment: Hello Shivaji, Can you confirm me, that you have looked at your child categories and their Achor properties are "Yes" as there is no point in looking on code when your settings are different on admin panel. Try to use default filter file as magento provides this and child categories will not appear in filter unless they have products assigned to them. Try this if it doesn't work then we will look onto template and block.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the method [Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::renderCategoriesMenuHtml](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation.html#renderCategoriesMenuHtml). Something like this should show all categories:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/navigation')->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(); ?>
```

If you do not see the subcategories, make sure that they are not hidden by CSS.